# Any way to Flavour a Cider crafted with Baking yeast?

Tags: yeast, cider, flavor, brewing

I'm very new to brewing, and I'm making a couple test batches of cider as we speak. However my accessibility to things like wine or champagne yeast, so i'm stuck with baking yeast.

My question is when i'm done if i'm not happy with the taste is it possible for me to freeze my cider and add sweetener? Would sugar work or would I have to use a honey or other substitute?

Comment: Other than the baking yeast, what are the ingredients?

Answer (score 1):

If you freeze and add sugar later ... remember that it could start to ferment again.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, you really don't want to ferment with baking yeast. Yes, you can modify taste afterwards, but it's probably not worth the trouble.